# show one panel after button is clicked and other panel when second button is clicked in the same frame

Tags: java, swing, button, panel, frame

I am creating a Swing based application , which actually consist of two buttons as shown below -

[image: Main Interface]

now what i want is when first button is clicked it must perform a action like showing a panel containing label, textfields , and some buttons in the same frame as shown below -

[image: First button action]

and when second button is clicked it will show another panel in the same frame as shown below ..

[image: Second button]

the thing is i am not understanding how to make this interface in action by providing event handler and action listener .. So please letme me know how can i archive this . Any help would be appreciated  .. Thanks

Comment: What ever you are trying is called `tabbed pane` in java swings.. Check here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html

Comment: @AJ. I am sure  its not tabbed pane ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 approaches.

1. `CardLayout` based.
   Create all the panels (empty, panel with fields, panel with list) and add them in a container with `CardLayout` (the empty one is default). On click buttons swap visible cards (panels) showing necessary one.
2. Recreation based.
   On click button create a new panel with new content. Remove the old one from container and add the newly created pane. After then call:

   ```
   container.revalidate();
   container.repaint();
   ```

Comment: CardLayout it is .. can you mention any link to explain this kind of functioning tutorial .. i have searched but could not find .. but thanks this is exactly what i want .